# Dual Sim Oppo Reno Z - not receiving notification of voice messages or calls on 2nd sim

Tags: dual-sim

I use vodafone as my 2nd sim and Optus as my 1st. I'm not receiving any notification that I have a voice message on my 2nd sim. I also don't receive a notification that someone called on the 2nd sim.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. It was actually an issue with the sim itself and I had to ring the voicemail settings and chose sms notification - which it had already been set up with - again. Vodafone is hopeless or it's an issue with this sim. Thanks